# Windows Azure: asp.net <appsetting> for ChatHttpHandler not found

Tags: windows, azure, charts

I have a problem in setting the chartHttpHandler in web.config for windows azure

Initially I added a chartHttpHandler on my web.config file

```
<remove name="ChartImageHandler"/>
<add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
```

under system.webServer section

Then I got an error stating

```
Invalid temp directory in chart handler configuration [c:\TempImageFiles\].
```

Then I found that I should change in

```
From   
<add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;dir=c:\TempImageFiles\;" />

To
 <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;" />
```

I am not able to find this section in my web.config file. So I tried to add it under  section but it gave me error that `it is an invalid child`
Likewise, I tried adding it under  section, it too gave the same error...

So, I added sepeartely, Then I am not able to see anything.. The webpage is just blank...

What should I have to do.. Can anyone tell me "how to solve it"

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to add it in appSettings... http://blogs.msdn.com/deliant/archive/2008/12/02/managing-chart-generated-images-with-chart-image-handler.aspx

(No personal knowledge about this, but that's the first link I found via Bing.)

Comment: Yes.. Smarx.. I too know this.. But under which section should I have to add.. Is it either under <system.web> or <system.webServer>. When I tried adding it, I got error...

Comment: I believe it should be under neither.  <appSettings> is a direct descendant of <configuration>.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228154.aspx